# Positioning element regardless of window size

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm having some problems placing an element with a margin of  2%, regardless of the window size. I'm able to move the element using basic margin (%), but as soon as I resize the window, the element doesn't move along with it.

I just want it to be 2% from right side of the window - at all times - in all window sizes!

Any suggestions?

Now I just tried to add some text, and the following CSS:

```
    position:absolute;
text-decoration:underline;
text-align:right;
right:0;
width:15em;
top:-3%;
margin-right:1%;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:0.65em;
```

This won't stay at the right either! I can move it with margin, but only "left".

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you *position* the element *aboslutely*?

```
​#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
}​
```

Comment: Finally! Thought I had already tried this.. 

One thing though, it doesn't move all the way to the right, even if I use 0.1%.. Any idea why?

Comment: If you want the element to be totally on the right, just use `0` for `right.` Or do you want the element to be on the right but not its contents? Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/x4hCQ/

Comment: Worked it out :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1749428 You should also try Ivozor's solution if you're currently learning CSS. Here is nice article about floats: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/understanding-css-floats/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work? Don't mess with absolute! :P

```
float: right;
margin-right: 2%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qkXj/1/

Comment: `position: absolute` is not always bad, it depends on the usecase.

Comment: Absolutely, ComFreek! (See what I did there? :D ) Anyway, position absolute for beginners can be a headache, in my opinion.